# MySQL Workbench, keep getting error 1064 error

Tags: mysql, error-handling

Fairly new to SQL. Trying to create a db, but keep running into this issue?

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
>
> CONSTRAINT `fk_Vurdering_Fag`
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`Fag_Fagkode`)
>
> REF' at line 11

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `Vurderingsbase`.`Vurdering`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vurderingsbase`.`Vurdering` (
      `Vurderingsnr` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Dato` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `Karakter` INT NULL,
      `Type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      `Fag_Fagkode` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Vurderingsnr`, `Fag_Fagkode`),
      INDEX `fk_Vurdering_Fag_idx` (`Fag_Fagkode` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Vurdering_Fag`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Fag_Fagkode`)
        REFERENCES `Vurderingsbase`.`Fag` (`Fagkode`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Does anybody have a idea about what could be wrong? i have reaserched the topic on here and other place. None of the solutions worked for me:(

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a
>   key, use UNIQUE instead

You had defined attribute `Fag_Fagkode` as NULL. Changed it to UNIQUE. Check if this works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vurderingsbase`.`Vurdering` (
      `Vurderingsnr` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Dato` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `Karakter` INT NULL,
      `Type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      `Fag_Fagkode` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Vurderingsnr`, `Fag_Fagkode`),
      INDEX `fk_Vurdering_Fag_idx` (`Fag_Fagkode` ASC) ,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Vurdering_Fag`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Fag_Fagkode`)
        REFERENCES `Vurderingsbase`.`Fag` (`Fagkode`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Check your referencing table column `Fagkode` has the same data type as :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vurderingsbase`.`Fag` (
      `Fagkode` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
      `Fag` VARCHAR(255) NULL NULL,
      `Uketimer` INT NULL 
 )
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that. Did not work:( still same error code

Comment: I have updated the answer! Pls, check if that works!

Comment: Thanks,i think it fixed that issue. But now i get this; https://imgur.com/a/dVFJLn5. Should i delete the other primary? because i get another error then

Comment: sorry it did not, i posted the answer as a accicent, i have edited it.

Comment: Yes remove the line PRIMARY KEY(`Fagkode`) and try again

Comment: Ok, i tried that. But get this error again, i tried to put that parenthesis after unique primare key, but no luck. https://imgur.com/a/yq47AjN

Comment: edited answer this should fix it

Comment: Still get the same error:( https://imgur.com/a/WdZCJsd

Comment: My bad! check now! Copy the exact same code

Comment: I think that worked. But getting another error. https://imgur.com/a/BH2EMWM ,https://imgur.com/a/C0yYjmg

Comment: just add a semicolon after 1st table creation like ENGINE = InnoDB; check answer again

Comment: Seems like a never ending cycle, sorry for bothering so much. Still error, https://imgur.com/a/9KGBvU7

Comment: Try removing VISIBLE and try !

Comment: Thanks alot. Finally worked. God bless you;)

Comment: Glad that helped. Can you mark answer as accepted?